# With Google Sheets, how to have entered data automatically sent to a specific range group?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to fill these price ranges with 100 products each: $10-$20 range, $15-$25 range, and $20-$30 range.

You can see the ranges overlap. When I have a $17 product, I've been manually copying-and-pasting its information to the $10-$20 section and the $15-$25 section.

I was wondering if there's a way to just enter the $17 product somewhere, and have its information automatically appear in whatever ranges it fits?

Comment: Hi and welcome. _not even sure how to phrase the question to Google to find what I mean._ Yep-been there, done that too. Let's start with your question - we can't visualise your data which means we can't reproduce your scenario. Would you please include a spreadsheet with some sample data OR include a screenshot showing the layout of your product information and price range columns AND the structure and layout of the price data. For example, how do we know it is a "$17 product"? And where do we look for the data to go in the "$10-$20 section" and/or the "$15-$25 section"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. 

I might have spoken too soon. Just found a tutorial for what I was trying (and failing) to describe lol. It's a query. 

Now I have a master list sheet with all the products and prices on it, and each group has its own sheet with =QUERY('Master list'!A2:H1000, select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H WHERE (F >=minimum price AND F<=maximum price)

 Sorry for not including an example. I'll make sure to do that next time. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. Checkout the tag wiki for basic guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a tutorial for what I was trying (and failing) to describe. It's a query.

Now I have a master list sheet with all the products and prices on it, and each price group has its own sheet with `=QUERY('Master list'!A2:H1000, SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H WHERE (F >=minimum price AND F<=maximum price)`